Condition of function execution
I have a very simple problem but I don't see any obvious solution.
Consider the below image. I have a value which constantly changes. I can either inject a new value on every change (which is frequent) or every 5 seconds (even more frequent).
However, I would like to only use the current value once every 24 hours.
How can I make function 1 only get triggered when mode:0 is injected and prevent it from reexecuting each time the BMS SOC value is injected?
My use case is quite simple. Each evening, I would like to calculate the charge current needed to have the batteries fully charged by morning.
One idea was to use a delay node, but while it would limit the frequency of the argument injection, I don't see a way to make it pass the message specifically at 22:15.
I'm open to any suggestions
Thanks for your help


You are going to need to explain in more detail what you are looking for here as it really isn't clear from your description. Because the simplest solution as you've described it is to just remove the link from the BMS node to the function node.

sorry if I was unclear. I want to have a single input to the function (SOC) but I don't want every input change/refresh to trigger the function execution.
Instead, I want to have a seperate control over when the function gets executed, in this case it will be the injection of "mode:0" number.
To put it in a more descriptive manner, I want to determine once every evening, what charge current is necessary to be fully charged by morning based on current state of charge from the batteries

Again I don't see why you don't just remove the link from the BMS node to but if you mean you want to take the first input from the BMS node after the inject node then a delay node can be used to rate limit to once a day, and the inject node can reset it. Please edit the question to add a LOT more details.

I honestly don't understand the confusion. The question is quite simple and I believe the original description passes the message.
I want to have one meaningful argument, but it's not possible to inject it once per day at given hour so I need a different trigger for the execution. Adding a delay node is not good enough as far as I can tell (I explored this option) because it's not possible to define at what time it will be released. Simple rate limiting is not what I'm looking for.
either way, I'll edit the question if it's not understandable

The reset, trigger on the delay node will release of the next message sent by the BMS node, and inject nodes can be configured to fire at a specific time. Or the trigger node (again in reset mode)

I never figured out the exact answer to my own question, likely this is not possible.
However I did find a workaround. Instead of having an "actual" and "triggering" arguments to the function, I instead assign the "actual" argument to a global variable (flow level variable would do as well) and then I'm able to inject it at the chosen time no matter how often the value changes. Hope this may help someone

